# Use LLDB to create a std::vector convenience variable

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, std, lldb

While in my thread stack, I want to create a convenience variable that uses the vector constructor in the standard library. I have looked into the documentation [LLDB Doc](https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html#evaluating-expressions) for variable construction but it only allows simple variables.

I have tried the following and received the error listed below...

```
(lldb) expr std::vector<int> $vec_temp(vec.begin(), vec.begin()+mid)
error: <user expression 12>:1:6: too few template arguments for class template 'vector'
std::vector<int> $vec_temp(vec.begin(), vec.begin()+mid)
     ^
note: template is declared here
```

If there is a gdb equivalent, that would be great to see.

Comment: Are there symbols in your binary for the constructor you are trying to use? My understanding is that a lot of the STL vanishes when compilation & linking are done, which is why a lot of expressions are no longer valid when executing them in LLDB.

Comment: @merlinND Given that `std::vector` is a template class, this is even more likely. I would be surprised if any debugger could instantiate an `std::vector<int>` if that specific template, *specifically of `<int>`*, wasn't instantiated in any compilation units.

Comment: hmm not sure, I am kind of a beginner at C++ and debugging with lldb. How can I check the symbols table for my binary? Also how should it look like to show if the constructor is there?

Comment: @Interlooper On my machine, the `vector<int>` symbols all start with `_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIiSaIiEE`. If you run `nm <name_of_executable_file>` you'll see the list of symbols. If it's not there, could you try an [explicit instantiation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation) or making some dummy function that uses a `vector<int>` in some way?

Comment: @nanofarad I see something similar with `nm main | grep vector`, a lot of symbols found starting with `__ZNSt3__16vectorIiNS_9allocatorIiEEE`, is this okay?

Comment: @nanofarad I could create a dummy variable and use that in my thread stack under lldb but I was hoping for a way to just create it under the lldb application

Comment: Could you share the full name of one of those symbols so I could put it through a demangler and see what C++ name it corresponds to? (I'm setting up lldb right now so I can also test, but my Internet connection is slow)

Comment: @nanofarad Yes definitely! Here is some of the interesting symbols `__ZNSt3__16vectorIiNS_9allocatorIiEEEC1Ev`,
`__Z10merge_sortRNSt3__16vectorIiNS_9allocatorIiEEEE`, 
`__ZNKSt3__113__vector_baseIiNS_9allocatorIiEEE7__allocEv`

Comment: @nanofarad I am creating a merge_sort application for fun btw, I can post this code as well or maybe even create a GitHub repo for it

Comment: @Interlooper I'm a bit confused now, since that symbol looks like it's related to `std::vector<int>`. Unfortunately I'm having trouble installing lldb (I broke my package manager) so I can't double check what's going on.

Comment: @nanofarad I think it could probably work in another debugger if you wanna try it there and I can then figure out how to translate it to lldb?

Comment: @Interlooper I'll have to get back to you on that; unfortunately fixing my package manager is a higher priority since it can block me on important schoolwork (and a broken libc is probably not the best environment for trying debuggers since it can cause confusion from other issues arising). An extra `std::vector<int>` declared in your program is probably the best workaround for now.

Comment: @nanofarad Okay that is fine, let me know when you get around to it.